# How to traverse to the particular element attribute

Tags: 2013, xslt

I have an xml like this

```
 <text>
                <p>asd</p>

                <p>sdd</p>

                <p style="text-decoration: underline;">asa</p>

                <p>asd</p>

                <p>asad</p>
 </text>
```

And my xslt is:-

```
<xsl:template name="f1" match="*[local-name()='p']">
    <xsl:variable name="v1" select="@style"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$v1 != contains($v1,'text-decoration: underline;')">
        <xsl:variable name="tagName" select="name()" />
        <xsl:element name="{$tagName}" namespace="{$nSpace}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="$v1 = contains($v1,'text-decoration: underline;')">
          <xsl:element name="u" namespace="{$nSpace}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

My xslt is generating the output in this way:-

```
<text>
            <u>asd</u>

            <u>sdd</u>

            <u>asa</u>

            <u>asd</u>

            <u>asad</u>
</text>
```

I need output in this way

```
<text>
                <p>asd</p>

                <p>sdd</p>

                <p><u>asa</u></p>

                <p>asd</p>

                <p>asad</p>
    </text>
```

Can anyone help me to get this output. What changes are required in my xslt?
Suggestions Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a generic XML/XSLT question and not specific to Tridion. 
But here's how I would write it (having not seen the rest of your XSLT and ignoring the $nSpace part):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="p[contains(@style, 'text-decoration: underline')]">
        <p><u><xsl:value-of select="."/></u></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- By default, copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->   
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first template matches the one you care about: paragraphs with an underline style. The second template just copies everything else. That is a good starting point to transform XML where you just need to make tweaks: copy everything by default and then handle the exceptions.